# MSM site - cannot get addon site to use its own template

Tags: multi-site-manager

I have installed MSM and set up three sites, “live”, “beta” and “internal”.
Edited the “live” site, created a default template group called “Live” and edited the index template in that group.
Now I’m editing the “beta” site.  I created a default template group there called “Beta” and edited the index template in that group.
The problem is: when I go to the URL for the “beta” site, I still get shown the index template for the “live” site!
How do I debug this problem?
I have tried changing uri_protocol to PATH_INFO in the live site’s config.php and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Sounds like your MSM environment isn't set up correctly. You'd need to detail how you have things setup so we can pinpoint what isn't correct.

Comment: It was the Apache virtual hosts that were wrong.  Would be great to see more detailed example information in the installation docs, eg. a checklist with examples for common configurations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, it was the Apache virtual hosts setup that was wrong.